factory methods in JPA entity classes. anti pattern?
I started using factory methods in JPA Entity classes. But I'm not sure if it's an anti-pattern. If it is , then where do I place them instead ?
A similar sample is below
@Builder
@Entity
Class EntityA {
    public static EntityA fromSomeClass(SomeClass sc){
       return builder.id(sc.id).name(sc.name).build();
    }
    public static EntityA fromAnotherClass(AnotherClass ac){
       builder.id(ac.id).name(ac.name).somethingACSpecific("xyz").build();
    }
}


I don't recognise the syntax. What language is this? Groovy?

it's just pseudo. I'm using java. Added more details now

Don't concern yourself with patterns. If it fits there, it fits there. And even if you find a valid reason later on to think this is the wrong place, moving a method is a refactoring no-brainer nowadays, as long as you don't publish a publicly accessible library.

@kommradHomer I don't see constructors. I do see factory methods that use builders. Nothing hinky so far.

@candied_orange if instance methods are used as a definition for the serialization format, adding static methods to the mix is icky. Similar to having a mix of generated and authored code.

@kommradHomer could you add some fields to the example to demonstrate that JPA is actually used?

@Basilevs oh you're right of course. But I've given up arguing with people that assume a method that doesn't use instance state should be static. I could argue that it doesn't use static state either but that just confuses them by making sense.

@candied_orange well, you confused me too :) JPA has requirements on methods it uses, this has nothing to do with opinions. It is a mess of reflection.

@Basilevs do please explain.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

This is almost a duplicate of Is it a bad idea to put externally dependent logic in ORM classes?

@Basilevs the methods are not used by JPA. But the class itself is an entity class that a JPA repository uses
